# Set and Clear Timeout on Node Server from Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm attempting to allow a user to set an alarm from the client and pass it to the server. The server then has a setTimeout that counts down and when time runs out, executes the function.

This first part is working fine, however, I need the the ability to clear that same timeout, should the client decide to cancel that particular alarm.

Note: I've been storing various data using Redis, so that is available.

```
var client = redis.createClient();
io.set("store", new sio.RedisStore);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('alarm:config', function(list, date, time, bool) {

  if (bool) {

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var year = date[0],
        month = date[1] - 1,
        day = date[2];

    var hour = time[0],
        minutes = time[1];

    var alarm = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes);

    var countdown = alarm - now;

    var myAlarm = setTimeout(function() {

      // do stuff...

    }, ( countdown ) );

  } else {

    clearTimeout(myAlarm);

  }

});
});
```

The approach I have in mind is that I would use the boolean value to determine if the user is setting or canceling that particular alarm. **I realize that setting a local variable "myAlarm" will not work, I just put it there to convey the idea.**

I am trying to figure out a way to store a reference to that exact timeout so that the next time the "alarm:config" socket event is triggered with a false boolean value, it can cancel the timeout that was set earlier.

It might be another question all together, but how does an application like Google Calendar store a date and time and then know exactly when to trigger it as well as offer the ability to cancel it? This would essentially be the same idea.

**UPDATE: I have it working using the following solution. I am open to a more elegant solution.**

```
socket.on('alarm:config', function(list, date, time, bool) {

  var alarmName = "timer:" + list;

  if (bool) {

    client.hset(alarmName, "status", true);

    var now = new Date().getTime();

    var year = date[0],
        month = date[1] - 1,
        day = date[2];

    var hour = time[0],
        minutes = time[1];

    var alarm = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes);

    var countdown = alarm - now;

    setTimeout(function() {

      client.hget(alarmName, "status", function(err, bool) {

        if(bool == 'true') {

          // do stuff...

        } else {

          console.log("This alarm has been canceled.");

        }

      });

    }, ( countdown ) );

  } else {

    console.log('canceling alarm');
    client.hset(alarmName, "status", false);

  }
});
```

Comment: How about you let clients handle the timeouts and the server only manages storage of alarm timestamps?

Comment: That's food for thought. I'll definitely keep that in mind. Based on the requirements however, I don't think that will work. The timeout function is going to set in motion an event that will affect other users. If the originating user were to turn off his phone or close his browser, the action should still run.

Comment: The return value of `setTimeout()` is the "reference to that exact timeout". Why don't you return that to the client?

Comment: @Tomalak - When the timer goes off, it's actually going to notify other users as well as the source. This might be an interesting approach.. Are you suggesting I send the timeout itself to all of the various clients, so that they have a reference to it. And should that timeout be cancelled by the creator, tell all of the other clients to clear that timeout? That might work nicely.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, exactly. As I understood it, there is only one machine that actually *runs* the timeout, and any number of machines that "know about" it. The timeout ID as returned by `setTimeout()` would be the natural candidate to pass around.

Comment: While I like this solution, it adds a level of concern - managing each client's instance of the setTimeout.If I am managing it on the Node server and it is cancelled, it will never be sent to the other clients. If it deploys to all of the clients on instantiation,

Comment: While I like this solution, it adds a large level of concern - Managing each client's instance of the setTimeout. 

If I'm managing the timeout on the server and it gets cancelled, the message will never be sent to the other clients. If the timeout deploys to all clients on instantiation and one user loses connectivity for 5 minutes, during which time, the creator cancels the alarm, that specific client would not get the cancellation and thus his setTimeout would still run.

This approach is a bit too fragile for my requirements, but thanks for sharing it. I'm glad I learned this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large of an application you're building, there are a couple of options.

## Processing Queue

You could restructure your application to use a job queue instead of simply setting timers. This has an advantage that you can split it in the future into multiple processes, but it does complicate the handling a bit.

A library like [Kue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue) uses just Redis and allows you to do a delayed put to set events in the future.

Going from the Kue readme:

```
var kue = require('kue')
  , jobs = kue.createQueue();

// Create delayed job (need to store email.id in redis as well)
var email = jobs.create('email', {
    title: 'Account renewal required',
    to: 'tj@learnboost.com',
    template: 'renewal-email'
}).delay(minute).save();

// Process job
jobs.process('email', function(job, done){
  email(job.data.to, done);
});

// Cancel job
email.remove(function(err){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('removed completed job #%d', job.id);
});
```

## Storing Reference to Timeout

This is much less robust, but could allow you to do it very simply. It leaves global variables floating around, and has no recovery if the process crashes.

Basically, you store the timer in a global variable and cancel it based on the job id.

```
var myAlarms = {}

socket.on('alarm:config', function(list, date, time, bool) {
  var alarmName = "timer:" + list;

  if (bool) {

    myAlarms[alarmName] = setTimeout(function() {
      // do stuff...
    }, countdown);

  } else {
    clearTimeout(myAlarms[alarmName]);
  }
}
```

*Note: None of this code has been tested and it likely contains errors.*